# Run time exception: unable to instantiate activity component

Tags: android, facebook

Trying to Integrate facebook sdk to android app but my app is not starting. There are the logs. How can I fix this runtime exception?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

 08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sri.z4globalsoft/com.sri.z4globalsoft.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1879)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at com.sri.z4globalsoft.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:23)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  ... 11 more
```

Tried by changing the code ap per your answers given below then also having problem

```
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.Facebook
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.sri.z4globalsoft.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:25)
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-15 12:25:00.800: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: logs won't help unless you post some code. What's on line 23 ?

Comment: You didn't import your Facebook sdk properly...

Comment: line 23-->String APP_ID = getResources().getString(R.string.APP_ID);

Comment: you sure you have APP_ID at your string resources?

Comment: Post code of onCreate.

Comment: yes ,it is in string resource

Comment: placed oncreate(),could you please look in to it.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you might be trying to use `getResources()` before they are technically ready.

If you have this:

```
String APP_ID = getResources().getString(R.string.APP_ID);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
}
```

Do this instead:

```
String APP_ID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    APP_ID = getResources().getString(R.string.APP_ID);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
08-15 11:48:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at com.sri.z4globalsoft.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:23)
```

You're trying to initialize a member variable where the initialization is using `this` as `Context`. In this case it's the `getResources()` call. You can only use the `Activity` as a `Context` in `onCreate()` or later in the activity lifecycle.

Specifically (from question comments), change this:

```
String APP_ID = getResources().getString(R.string.APP_ID);
```

to something like:

```
String APP_ID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    APP_ID = getResources().getString(R.string.APP_ID);
    //...
```

Comment: edited my code acoording to u r answer but problem didn't fixed yet.could u please check my edits in the question.